# How to optimize .json lookup RegEx?

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that matches a value of a particular `.json` properties.

Imagine that you `.json` string looks like the following:

`{\"id\":\"firstId\",\"cardData\":{\"bar\":\"firstBar\",\"foo\":\"firstFoo\",\"number\":\"firstNumber\"}}`

and you want to match the values of `bar` and `foo`. In order to achieve it, I created this RegEx:

```
(?<=\"(?i)bar\":\"|(?i)foo\":\")[^\"]++
```

Can you advise me on a better one?
It works but I bet there must be something better simply because I am not RegEx expert at all and it was the first solution that I came up with.

Comment: What is better than one that works ? Does it work ?

Comment: It works but I bet there must be smth better